# which one of the following hold for all continuous function $f : [-\pi ,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis

which one of the following  hold For all  continuous  function $f : [-\pi ,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

$a)$ If $f(-t) =-f(t)$ for  each $t \in [-\pi,\pi]$,then $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)dt=0$

$b)$  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(-t)dt=- \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)dt $

My attempt :  I thinks  option b) will  hold

and  option  a) will not hold  because  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)dt=2\int_{0}^{\pi}f(t)dt \neq 0$

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually both option you have given are equivalent. (Check b if you have some typos)

And both are correct . As function is odd so if you integrate it you get even function and by subtracting you get 0

Comment: ya,,u r  saying right     i have  edited its now,,,,see again

Answer (score 0):

It looks on the face of it that the other answer (the first you've got - this is the second) is just *plainly obviously* correct ... but in the abstract theory of functions I have seen so many ingeniously constructed 'pathological' functions that somehow manage to *defy & foil* what appear on the face of it to be the plainest of truths that I wouldn't even venture say with *absolute* certainty that $x=-x\implies x=0$.

**Update**

You have to be really careful looking at these, don't you, as it's so easy to make a little slip.

As for (a), it's just saying that the function is odd ... and therefore that the integral is 0, because every $\operatorname{f}(-t)dt$ is cancelled by  a $\operatorname{f}(+t)dt$

But then (b) is stated *independently* of (a): if you're not careful, you can presume that the condition in (a) *carries over* into (b). And then another point you have to be careful about is that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\operatorname{f}(-t)dt$$ is ***not*** $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\operatorname{f}(t)dt$$ with $-t$ substituted for $t$, but simply the integral of the function $\operatorname{g}(t)$ obtained by reflecting $\operatorname{f}(t)$ about $t=0$ ... meaning that in doing the integral it is *the same integral* but just carried out in *reverse order*. So (b) does not hold *in general*, but  only when (a) applies ... in which case it's true by reason only of the *being zero* of the integral.

All this of course precludes any consideration of the sort of *pathological* function I was talking about at first, that can spring allmanner of surprise. But *that* is probably precluded by the continuity requirement anyway.

Answer (score 0):

option b) is false

$\displaystyle \underset{[-1,1]}\inf f\int_{-1}^{1}dt\le\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt\le \underset{[-1,1]}\sup f\int_{-1}^{1}dt\iff 2\underset{[-1,1]}\inf f\le\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt\le 2\underset{[-1,1]}\sup f$

so $f: x\to \cos^2(x)$ is counterexample

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}\cos^2(t)dt =\int_{0}^{1}1+\cos(2t)dt=\bigg[t+\dfrac{\sin(2t)}{2}\bigg]^1_0=1+\dfrac{\sin2 }{2}>1\ge f(x)\ge0,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$